# Making Ajax request on Android returns No Transport error

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have developed a sample app on Android using Phonegap.
When clicked on a button, an Ajax request is made to the server (***http://192.168.0.199:8080/test.php***).
The *test.php* just echoes **hello world**.
I am using **Jquery 1.5** for making the Ajax call.

Here is the code for the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({  
 url:"http://192.168.0.199:8080/test.php",  
 beforeSend: function(x) {
 alert("The URL "+url);  
},
type:'POST',  
crossDomain: true,
success:function(data) {  
  alert(data);  
},  
error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
 alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
 alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
 alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  
}
});
```

But, every time this function is called, it throws an error:

`Error Type: No Transport`
`Error Message: undefined`
`Error Status: error`

**Note: I have added the INTERNET Permission in the Manifest file. I am using a G1 device running Android 1.6**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to make an call to a client within a local network.
Try validating you have access to that local network.

Comment: Hi Erik, i am able to access the url on the browser...definitely not a network issue.

Comment: It runs fine on a **Samsung Galaxy S** on **Android 2.2** Maybe it's a version problem...the G1 is running on **Android 1.6**

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.5 a new AJAX / XHR implementation is in use. And Android 1.5 / 1.6 doesn't say it supports CORS (crossdomain calling). So a way to 'fix' that is to inform jQuery it *does* support cors:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

I couldn't reproduce the problem on 2.1 and up. So I expect the XHR implementation from that version on does say it does support cors.