# updating the cache in Android webview causes the jQuery ajax call to return error

Tags: jquery, android, html, caching, webview

If I add a html5 manifest property to my html tag it causes my jQuery ajax call to return an error although the request reaches the server. It is implemented in Android webview using PhoneGap.

P.S. I realized that it works fine in Firefox and it is only happening in Android's webview.

Comment: Checkout this answer, if your android version id 1.5/1.6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104539/making-ajax-request-on-android-returns-no-transport-error

Comment: Shraddha actually this error happens only if I add a manifest property to my html tag. Otherwise everything works fine.

Comment: doesn't anybody know about this issue?